# Is it valid to add energy densities of *interacting* perfect fluids?

Tags: special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, cosmology, superposition, interactions

In several papers on *interacting perfect fluids* in cosmology, the authors assume that we still can add the energy densities and pressures of the individual fluids, as if there wasn't any interaction:
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\rho &= \sum_i \rho_i,
&p &= \sum_i p_i.
\end{align}
For example:

https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.1086

https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.01143

https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.06410

The mutual interactions are described by the arbitrary function $Q_i$ that is added to the right part of the differential equation which describe the local conservation of energy for each fluid:
$$\tag{2}
\frac{d\rho_i}{dt} + 3 \frac{\dot{a}}{a} (\rho_i + p_i) = Q_i.
$$
How can we justify that (1) are still valid for interacting perfect fluids?  Is this just a "working hypothesis"?

I have the feeling that all the interaction terms hidden inside $\rho_i$ and $p_i$ are simply moved to the right side of equation (2), and that (1) (without any interaction terms) is actually a *definition* of the "mixture".  Does that have any physical sense?